# Open standalone player directly from command line without configuration popup

Tags: unity-game-engine, command-line, command-line-arguments

Using windows 7 and unity 5.3, I want to open the player without the first popup which ask about configuration Like screen resolution and graphic quality etc as mention in Picture.

[image]

I want to open the scene directly but these configuration I want to provide through command line and batch file. I checked Unity docs about command line but it did not work for me I tried this command line but still showing the popup.

```
E:\Player\StreamerPlayer.exe -screen-width 800 -screen-height 600 -screen-quality fantastic
```

Is there any way available to play standalone from command line and provide all parameter thought it and open scene directly?

Comment: PS Mohammad is this on Windows (which one, 10?) or Mac?

Comment: windows 7 and unity 5.3

Answer (score 3):

Go to File/Build Settings/Player Settings and then check out the Standalone Player Options where you set the Display Resolution Dialog to Disabled.

Comment: Hi @jankigadhiya. This is the perfect answer.  Note that this question is about Unity3D.  There's no problem at all with answers being short, if, they contain full information.  Riley has given the full answer here.

Comment: @riley thanks for input i know this thing please read full question.

Comment: @JoeBlow it addressing one aspect of the question not complete

Comment: @jankigadhiya Turns out I read the question wrong, my bad.

OP, you already turned this off in the settings then?

Comment: @jankigadhiya if i open through cmd then i want to provide popup setting to cmd

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan You already changed the setting in the player settings? Else I'll look around a bit mroe

Comment: @Riley change the setting will definealty work but i want to provide those settings through command line & batch file. is this possible?

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan you can try using command line arguments
http://docs.unity3d.com/420/Documentation/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html

Comment: @Riley i tried this and command mention already in the question. it didn't work for me.

Comment: Then I wouldn't know, my apologies.